# How do I convert a list member to a number from a list while working in a file?

Tags: python

```
inputFile = open("Students_1.txt" , 'w')
inputFile.write("John Smith 80 90\n")
inputFile.write("Ryan Brown 80 60\n")
inputFile.write("Anna Myers 95 85\n")
inputFile.close()

inputFile = open("Students_1.txt" , 'r')
for line in inputFile:
    y = line.split()
    print(y)
```

This is the code I have so far but I am stuck trying to figure out how to convert it to an integer.

Comment: What specifically you want to convert to an interger?

Comment: Just the numbers in the code because i have to find the average of the numbers in each line then print the average of each persons grade and print it next to the second number in each line

Answer (score 1):

you can use `int(var)` to convert a variable value to an integer.
if the variable passed in `int()` function is not convertible to an integer then `int()` will through the exception(*ValueError: invalid literal for int()*).You can use below `parse_to_number()` to convert any variable value to integer.

```
def parse_to_number(var):
    try:
        return int(var)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
inputFile = open("Students_1.txt" , 'w')
inputFile.write("John Smith 80 90\n")
inputFile.write("Ryan Brown 80 60\n")
inputFile.write("Anna Myers 95 85\n")
inputFile.close()
inputFile = open("Students_1.txt" , 'r')
for line in inputFile:
    y = line.split()
    first_name = y[0]
    last_name = y[1]
    first_num = parse_to_number(y[2])
    sec_num = parse_to_number(y[3])
    print(first_num,sec_num)
```

Comment: Thank you so much appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert string numbers to integers, modify your `for` loop.

```
for line in inputFile:
    y = map(lambda v: int(v) if v.isdigit() else v, line.split())
    print(y)
```